# Untick a checkbox during testing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, integration-testing, laravel-5.1

Doing something like this:

```php
$this->visit('/path')
    ->check('field')
    ->push('Save');
```

Will submit a form with the `field` checkbox ticked regardless of its initial state.

How do I submit the same form with the checkbox un-ticked when it was pre-ticket in the form response? Laravel's crawler doesn't seem to provide a method to do this.

I've tried going through the underlying `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Form`:

```php
$visit = $this->visit('/path');
$form = $visit->getForm('Save');
$form['field'] = 0;
```

But that triggers the following error:

```
Input "unique_parcel" cannot take "0" as a value (possible values: 1).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using v5.1.10+ of the `laravel/framework` package, then you can use the `uncheck()` method.

```
$this->visit('/path')
     ->uncheck('field')
     ->push('Save');
```

Otherwise, you can use the `untick()` method.

```
$form = $visit->getForm('Save');
$form['field']->untick();
```

Comment: Ah, I am on 5.1.8 which explains why I couldn't find anything useful when looking through the source, thanks.